# How to pass a csv list into XML findall and get back matching children

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Here I want to pass in a csv list into my python code to retrieve only the Childone values that match in the csv list. What is the correct way to do this?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET    
import csv        
tree = ET.parse("C:/Users/thisuser/Desktop/stack.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

with open('C:/Users/thisuser/Desktop/stack.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = list(reader)

for ticket in root.findall('.//Parent'):
    Childone = ticket.find('.//Childone').text
    for Childone in your_list:

        for ticket2 in ticket.findall('.//ParentTwo'):
            Childtwo = ticket2.find('.//Childtwo').text
            print "Childone={Childone}, Childtwo={Childtwo}".format(Childone=Childone, Childtwo=Childtwo)
```

Desired Result

```
ChildOne=2  ChildTwo=c
ChildOne=2  ChildTwo=d

ChildOne=3  ChildTwo=c
ChildOne=3  ChildTwo=e
```

Current result

```
Childone=['2'], Childtwo=a
Childone=['2'], Childtwo=b
Childone=['3'], Childtwo=a
Childone=['3'], Childtwo=b
Childone=['2'], Childtwo=c
Childone=['2'], Childtwo=d
Childone=['3'], Childtwo=c
Childone=['3'], Childtwo=d
Childone=['2'], Childtwo=c
Childone=['2'], Childtwo=e
Childone=['3'], Childtwo=c
Childone=['3'], Childtwo=e
```

XML SAMPLE

```
<Parent>
    <Childone>1</Childone>
        <ParentTwo>
            <Childtwo>a</Childtwo>
        </ParentTwo>
        <ParentTwo>
            <Childtwo>b</Childtwo>
        </ParentTwo>
</Parent>

<Parent>
    <Childone>2</Childone>
        <ParentTwo>
            <Childtwo>c</Childtwo>
        </ParentTwo>
        <ParentTwo>
            <Childtwo>d</Childtwo>
        </ParentTwo>
</Parent>

<Parent>
    <Childone>3</Childone>
        <ParentTwo>
            <Childtwo>c</Childtwo>
        </ParentTwo>
        <ParentTwo>
            <Childtwo>e</Childtwo>
        </ParentTwo>
</Parent>
```

EXCEL SAMPLE

[image]

I am getting this error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: What does "stack.csv" look like?

Comment: just two values. cell A1 = 2. cell A2 = 3. I tried to upload a screenshot and couldnt.

Comment: Ahh I see. I see the screenshot I just didn't realize that was the csv open in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over your csv and only process `Parent` elements that have a matching `Childone` element (using an [XPath predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#predicates)).

Also, you already know the `Childone` element value so you only need the `Childtwo` value...

**XML Input** (test.xml)

```xml
<doc>
    <Parent>
        <Childone>1</Childone>
        <ParentTwo>
            <Childtwo>a</Childtwo>
        </ParentTwo>
        <ParentTwo>
            <Childtwo>b</Childtwo>
        </ParentTwo>
    </Parent>

    <Parent>
        <Childone>2</Childone>
        <ParentTwo>
            <Childtwo>c</Childtwo>
        </ParentTwo>
        <ParentTwo>
            <Childtwo>d</Childtwo>
        </ParentTwo>
    </Parent>

    <Parent>
        <Childone>3</Childone>
        <ParentTwo>
            <Childtwo>c</Childtwo>
        </ParentTwo>
        <ParentTwo>
            <Childtwo>e</Childtwo>
        </ParentTwo>
    </Parent>
</doc>
```

**CSV** (test.csv)

```
2
3
```

**Python**

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse("test.xml")

with open('test.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if i:
            print ""
        for childtwo in tree.findall(".//Parent[Childone='{}']/ParentTwo/Childtwo".format(row[0])):
            print "ChildOne={childone}  ChildTwo={childtwo}".format(childone=row[0], childtwo=childtwo.text)
```

**Output**

```
ChildOne=2  ChildTwo=c
ChildOne=2  ChildTwo=d

ChildOne=3  ChildTwo=c
ChildOne=3  ChildTwo=e
```

Comment: This works perfect. What is "for i, row in enumerate(reader):" doing?

Comment: It's basically checking the current row number to determine whether or not a blank line should be output. The first row will have the index `0`, which is false, so no blank line is output.